# Get records from a table A related to a table B, which has children records in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this situation:

A table called "services" and another one "companies":

```
services
------------
id
code
companies_id

companies
------------
id
parent_id
```

Sample records:

```
services
---------------
id     code    companies_id
1      s1      1
2      s2      1
3      s3      2
4      s4      2
5      s5      3
6      s6      3

companies
---------------
id    parent_id
1     0
2     1
3     0
```

**services** relate to **companies** with *companies_id*. So that a company may have 0 to N services.

A company may have children companies, so that these ones relate to their parent with *parent_id*.

What I need is a query to get any record in services related to a given company (id:1) and its children companies.

I should get this (the services of company 1 and its children company 2):

```
services
------------------
id   code  companies_id
1      s1      1
2      s2      1
3      s3      2
4      s4      2
```

This is my try, but I don't seem to get the correct number of rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM services
INNER JOIN companies ON services.companies_id = companies.id 
LEFT JOIN companies as children_companies ON services.companies_id = children_companies.id 
WHERE (companies.id =1 OR children_companies.parent_id = 1)
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: to get the more clear requirement of your question,update with sample data & desired output

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal I've just added sample data to clarify my question

Comment: Which rows are you getting that you're not expecting to?

Comment: Well, according to a test in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f1d14/1, my query is correct using the sample. It's possible that there's another factor affecting the results. This was only a very shortened sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
select b.id, b.code, b.companies_id from companies a
join services b on a.id = b.companies_id
where b.companies_id = 1 or a.id in 
(select id from companies c where c.parent_id = 1)
```

Comment: Turns out my query was right. There was another factor in the more complex real case which was affecting the results. As far as I know, it's faster to use joins versus nested queries like the one you provide. Anyway, since yours is the only reply, I'll mark it as accepted.